# PostgreSQL not allowed the string values

Tags: php, postgresql

The following PostgreSQL query producing me the following error. But in my intuition everything is correct. I don't know why PostgreSQL making it wrong.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO test (sku) VALUES ("."3814TT82033102-2".")";
```

The `sku` filed is `VARCHAR(50)`  but why the postgres query not allowed my sku. I got the following

```
PHP Warning:  pg_exec(): Query failed: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "TT82033102"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO test (sku) VALUES (3814TT82033102-2)
                                           ^ in /home/nifras/Documents/User/working-dir/csv/functions/import-rules.php on line 11
```

Comment: Strings need to be enclosed in single quotes `'` in SQL. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I take back my comment, you're right.  But really the OP should be using statements, most likely.  That's another topic though.

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name It works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed my query as follow

```
$product_sku = $product[0];
$query = "INSERT INTO test (sku) VALUES ('$product_sku')";
```

The issue is strings should cover by singlw quotes

Thanks [a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a php expert, but I feel a bind parameter could be used.

```
$sku = '3814TT82033102-2';
$query = 'INSERT test (sku) VALUES VALUES(:sku)';
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindValue(':sku', $sku);
```